# SQL Server string operations

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a string composed of 'n' bit , i.e. `'010111000010...'`

Each bit represents a day (sql server datetime type), i.e. `2014-10-03 00:00:00.000`

I know only 2 dates: the date of the first bit of the string and the bit of the last one.

Consecutives bits represent consecutives dates, i.e. if the first bit (in this case '0') represents `2014-10-03 00:00:00.000`, the second (in this case '1') represents `2014-10-04 00:00:00.000`

I want to retrieve the date of all 0 (all bit having the value '0') and than check if these dates belong to the table 'DayOff' (DayOff_Date column)  by the simplest and quicker way and if possible without loop.

Can someone has the corresponding code to do that

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use Charindex on your string.
Then use that index

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

A CTE to pull each char with an ordinal that's added to the base date:

```
declare @str varchar(128) = '010111000010'
declare @pos int          = 1

;With T( pos, charbit ) as
(
    select @pos as pos, substring(@str, 1, 1)
    union all
    select pos + 1, substring(@str, pos + 1, 1)
    from T
    where pos <= len(@str) - 1
)
 select
    dateadd(DAY, pos, '2014-10-03 00:00:00.000')
from T
where charbit = 0 
option (MAXRECURSION 1000)


(No column name)
2014-10-04 00:00:00.000
2014-10-06 00:00:00.000
2014-10-10 00:00:00.000
2014-10-11 00:00:00.000
2014-10-12 00:00:00.000
2014-10-13 00:00:00.000
2014-10-15 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alex K. and Joakim L. The code given by Alex work in a query window but when I want to use the code within a function It generates the following error (in french): 'La sélection d'instructions incluses dans une fonction ne peut pas renvoyer les données à un client.' on the following instruction: ;With T( pos, charbit ) as ..                        How can I use the same code within a function. Thanks

Comment: Excuse me Alex. Your Code works very well. Thank you